# How Can I Disable Swiping Ball In A Certain Area of the Screen? (Swift ) (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Ok so currently in my game I have a ball that can be thrown. However, I want to make so that the user can only throw the ball past a certain point. I have been trying this for a while but I can't figure it out.  How can I do this?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch?
    let location = touch?.location(in: self)
    if ball.frame.contains(location!) {
        touchPoint = location!
        touching = true 
   }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch?
    let location = touch?.location(in: self)
    touchPoint = location!  
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touching = false
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    if touching  {
        let dt:CGFloat = 2.8/60.0
        let distance = CGVector(dx: touchPoint.x-ball.position.x, dy: touchPoint.y-ball.position.y)
        let velocity = CGVector(dx: distance.dx/dt, dy: distance.dy/dt)
        ball.physicsBody!.velocity=velocity
    }
}
```

Here, I have an image of my game so far. Currently, the ball can be dragged, thrown, or swiped anywhere on the screen. However, I want to make  so the ball can only be touched, thrown, or dragged below the middle of the screen. But I want the ball to continue being thrown if the user's finger accidently goes about the limit.

[image]

Comment: some further explanation or a diagram (even drawn) of what your you are trying to accomplish would go along way. Or show some examples of what you've tried so far

Comment: Added an image :) @RonMyschuk

Comment: " But I want the ball to continue being thrown if the user's finger accidently goes about the limit." - so is the idea here that the gesture has to START in the area on the bottom, but once started it continues to track it above the invisible line?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to adjust the coordinates for your bottom area based on actual size and game scene anchorPoint. for example "100" in the sample assumes that your scene has an anchorPoint of (0,0) and the size of the bottom scroll area is 100.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        guard location < 100 else { return }

        //if ball.frame.contains(location!) {
            touchPoint = location!
            touching = true 
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem. My scene has an SKCamera. Will it still work?

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't sill work. if you have to you could always check for touch location in camera if need be